# Delphi android FindComponent as Form

Tags: android, delphi, find, firemonkey, tform

I am making first android application and having problem with opening form.
I only have name of form written in firebird table, and need to find form (FindComponent) to open it.
On VCL this works, but when I start app on tablet then nothing happens, form isn't find.

```
var
Form: TForm;
begin
Form := Application.FindComponent(Table1FormName.Value) as TForm;
    if Assigned(Form) then
      Form.ShowModal;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved...
Form name must be
Table1FormName.value+_LgXhdpiPh
or
Table1FormName.value+_LgXhdpiTb

Comment: Please explain from where the "_LgXhdpiPh" part of the name comes.

Comment: In app folder was created Form1.LgXhdpiPh.fmx (original name of form was Form1.fmx, but when I made Android phone view in Delphi, then that file was automaticly created)